# Site validator indicates an error with required attribute in form

Tags: html, forms, validation, required

The validator at validator.w3.org is telling me:

*Error: Duplicate attribute required.
At line 1, column 4143
e="53" required> <label for="e*

The form works OK but for some reason the validator is telling me that first name, last name, return email, etc cannot have the same "required" attribute, which I assume is a fairly common requirement.

I guess I'm doing something wrong in my html. Any suggestions?

```
  <form action="orderxyz.php" method="POST" id="orderFormxyz">
                <div id="contactDiv">
                  <label for="firstname">First Name<span style="color: red !important;">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name.." style="width: 10vw;"
                    required>
                  <label for="lastname">Last Name<span style="color: red !important;">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name.." style="width: 10vw;"
                    required>
  //...etc

 <div class="formButtons" id="formBtnStock">
                  <div class="basicDiv" id="paypalNotice">
                    <div id="paypalAlert"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="myFormBtn sendResetBtn pulsingButton"
                      id="sendBtnStock">
                  </div>
                  <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="myFormBtn sendResetBtn" id="resetBtnStock">
                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: When I copy/paste this exact HTML into the W3C validator, it doesn't produce the error indicated.  There is also no instance of the indicated text `e="53" required> <label for="e` anywhere in the code shown.  Maybe you're trying to validate some *other* HTML and not what you're showing us?

Comment: Use a full attribute name/value pair. e.g. required="required".

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Buried in the code was a required="" in an input, along with the standard "required" at the end of the tag. So the validator was finding the error but not reporting it as a duplicate. So @David was on the mark.